# Configuration of GitHub Actions: Avoid running CI twice when merging PR into main

Tags: github, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am using GitHub a
ctions to manage my CI and the following events trigger my workflow:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: main
  push:
    branches: main
```

I observed the following "problem":
When I create a PR, the CI is run. If the test passes and I merge it into main, the tests are run again (which I don'
t want in specific cases). How can I setup my workflow such that the CI is not triggered when merging a PR, where the CI already passed for the PR?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You might consider an `if` conditional in your case:

> ### [`jobs.<job_id>.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif)
>
> You can use the `jobs.<job_id>.if` conditional to prevent a job from running unless a condition is met. You can use any supported context and expression to create a conditional.
>
> When you use expressions in an `if` conditional, you may omit the expression syntax `(${{ }})` because GitHub automatically evaluates the `if` conditional as an expression. For more information, see "[Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions)".

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == false
    . . .
```

That would still trigger the workflow, but it can *skip* the jobs in the workflow.

Alternatives exist in [this thread](https://github.community/t/trigger-workflow-only-on-pull-request-merge/17359), which deals with the opposite requirements ("Trigger workflow only on pull request merge"): it can be adapted to do what you need (*not* trigger a workflow, or at least do the same job twice, on PR merge)

Comment: I think one has to omit the ticks (replace 'false' with false)

Comment: @Sebastian OK. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I only really came to testing it now and it seems like it does not work, have you tried it yourself?

Comment: the reason being that the workflow is still triggered by the push to main, which is independent of the `github.event.pull_request.merged`

Comment: @Sebastian I did not test it directly. Let me know if you find the right syntax.